# Is the word 'harsh' equal to the word 'harshly' in "the sky [was] a harsh blue"?

Tags: meaning-in-context, word-meaning

https://ebooks.adelaide.edu.au/o/orwell/george/o79n/chapter1.1.html

The paragraph is below.

> Outside, even through the shut window-pane, the world looked cold. **Down in the street little eddies of wind were whirling dust and torn paper into spirals, and though the sun was shining and the sky a harsh blue, there seemed to be no colour in anything, except the posters that were plastered everywhere.** The black-moustachio’d face gazed down from every commanding corner. There was one on the house-front immediately opposite. BIG BROTHER IS WATCHING YOU, the caption said, while the dark eyes looked deep into Winston’s own.

I encountered questions in the sentence " Down in the street little eddies of wind were whirling dust and torn paper into spirals, and though the sun was shining and the sky a harsh blue, there seemed to be no colour in anything, except the posters that were plastered everywhere ".

Does the word "tear" mean "to pull something so that it separates into pieces" in the sentence "Down in the street little eddies of wind were whirling dust and torn paper into spirals"?

Does the word "spiral" mean "a circular curving line that goes around a central point while getting closer to or farther away from it" in the sentence "Down in the street little eddies of wind were whirling dust and torn paper into spirals"?

Is the word "harsh" equal to the word "harshly" in the sentence "the sky a harsh blue"?

Comment: I don't think this question should be closed. It might be difficult for a nns to understand why adverbial ***harshly*** can't be used above, given that it's valid to say, for example, *The sky was **disturbingly** blue.* @Li Xiaodong - it would be valid (though *unlikely* phrasing) as *...and the sky **harshly** blue* (without the indefinite article ***a***).

Comment: Consider: a bright pink;  a deep blue;  a pale yellow (expressing the visual quality of the color, its "hue"). But consider also adjectives that impart figurative qualities to the color:  a shrieking orange; an angry red; a sad gray.

Comment: I'm happy to confirm that [*Her face was **softly** pink*](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22face+was+softly+pink%22) and [*Her face was **soft** pink*](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22face+was+soft+pink%22) are both completely valid. But I wouldn't like to be drawn on what if any difference in *meaning* they might have, nor could I explain exactly what's going on at the syntactic level there.

Comment: I voted to close this question because you edited it to include three different questions. If you have three different questions, post them as three separate posts.

Answer (score 4):

The article *a* is a clue that *blue* is a noun, not an adjective itself.  *Harsh* modifies blue, and since *blue* is a noun, that means *harsh* has to be an adjective.

*-ly* turns adjectives into adverbs.  You would use *harshly* if modifying an adjective or adverb.

> She yelled at me harshly (modifies *yelled*)
>
> A harshly worded letter was given to me (modifies *worded* - *worded* is not a verb but an adjective modifying *letter*)

Comment: Indeed, "the sky was harshly blue" sounds poetic to me, while "the sky was a harshly blue" grates for obvious reasons.

Comment: With some trepidation, I refer you to the slightly related question by @CopperKettle ["I hate red color" or "I hate red": why exactly is the first option ungrammatical](http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/39737/i-hate-red-color-or-i-hate-red-why-exactly-is-the-first-option-ungrammatica)

Answer (score -2):

**harshly** is derived from **harsh** - the root word is **harsh**.

They mean the same thing, but in the context of that sentence you can only use **harsh** - never **harshly**

Comment: Please [edit] to include an explanation of *why* "harshly" cannot be used; answers without explanation do not teach the patterns of the language well.

Comment: Rather than saying you could "never" use _harshly_ in that sentence, it might be more accurate to say that you'd need to **restructure** the sentence to use the adverbial form,. e.g.: _though the sun was shining brightly and the sky harshly blue..._