# The right preposition after a house of/ in ... colour

Tags: prepositions, phrases

What is the right preposition in the phrase:

> She has a detached house **in** a yellow colour.

or

> She has a detached house **of** a yellow colour?

Comment: Any reason you don't simply say "She has a yellow detatched house."?

Comment: "She has a detached house painted yellow"? Related: "[I hate red color vs. I hate red](http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/39737/i-hate-red-color-or-i-hate-red-why-exactly-is-the-first-option-ungrammatica)

Comment: I am interested in this construction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Color names typically use *in*. E.g.:

> Do you have this shirt in blue?
>
> The sky was red in color.

*In* is definitely the better choice. However, to my ear this particular construction is also okay (if a little unusual sounding) with *of*. It follows the pattern of describing something using *of [adjective] [noun]*. E.g.:

> He is a man of mental clarity.
>
> This is a sword of impeccable craftsmanship.

This is not usually used with the noun *color*, with the exception of the phrase *person of color* (or *people of color*). This is never used with a color name, i.e. you would never say "A person of brown color" (that would probably offend people, as well as sounding strange). It's also not common to include an article in this construction. We do however have the well known phrase from The Wizard of Oz, *a horse of a different color*.

In short, *in* is acceptable and *of* is questionable.

Comment: What about the Louis Amstrong's song "What A Wonderful World" "I see trees of green" "I see skies of blue" and "clouds of white"?