# The Color red or the Red color

Tags: adjectives, word-order, adjective-order

I want some help with this: I have read:

> The color red is beautiful

Why don't we say "the red color" instead, taking into account that in English many times the adjective comes first. For example: *the blue car*, or *the red label*?

Comment: Your question may have already been answered in  [“I hate red color” or “I hate red”: why exactly is the first option ungrammatical](http://ell.stackexchange.com/q/39737/).

Comment: Also see *[“Do you like the color red” vs “Do you like the red color”?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/109283/)*

Answer (score 2):

Red is a color. You don't usually say "red (as an adjective) color"; the use of the red (as a noun) on its own (without color after it) means that you are talking about the color that's red.  The same rule applies to all colors, such as green, yellow, blue. However, the color can be used as an adjective  before other nouns.  For example, a red car, a green shirt.

So you can say:

Red is beautiful.

The color (that is) red is beautiful.

Answer (score 2):

The last word in the phrase is normally the subject, and the word(s) before it are modifiers to be more specific.

"Red is beautiful" and "The color red is beautiful" mean the same thing. The emphasis is on the abstract idea of red, anywhere. Specifying "the color red" rather than just "red" is unnecessary, but it is very common.

Saying "red color" puts the emphasis on color, and then specifies that you mean the red one. "The red color is beautiful" suggests that you are talking about colors that are present, and you're specifying the red one. For example if you're looking at a painting you might say the red color (in the painting) is beautiful.

Answer (score -4):

So, it means that when you say red color, or color red, it should be understood as the same; but gramatically, you are using two nouns referring to the same thing, which is redundant.

Comment: *The color red* is no more redundant than *my sister Mary*, and redundancy itself does not make something ungrammatical; in fact, there are probably hundreds of common pleonasms in idiomatic English ranging from *absolutely necessary* to *whether or not*.