# "the black colour" or "the colour black"?

Tags: grammar, articles, definite-article

Tell me please what is the most natural way to say the following.

> The colour black is my favourite of all colours.
>
> The black colour is my favourite colour.

Is the use of the definite article correct in the sentences, if it is not, then why?

Comment: Possibly related: **[I hate red color](https://ell.stackexchange.com/q/39737/2127)**

Comment: The most natural way of saying it would be: ***My favorite color is black*** You could also say *Of all the colors (in the rainbow/world etc.), my favorite (in absolute) is black.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**The colour black** refers to the color itself, *as color*.

> My favorite color is the color black.

**The black colour** refers (colloquially) to something that is black.

> Which car do you like, the red or the black?
>   -- I like the black color.

It's synonymous with "the black-colored one" or "the one that is black".

**The black color** can also refer informally to the color as an attribute of something:

> Do you like this car?
>   -- I do like the black color, but I'm not fond of sedans.

There, "the black color" is synonymous with "its black color" or "the particular quality of blackness of its paint".